Pro*C find where function is defined
I am using Pro*C. I am trying to find where a function is defined. I have searched the sqlca.h file. I have searched the $ORACLE_HOME/precomp/public directory. I have commented out all of my #include which was recommended somewhere else. The only thing left is the EXEC SQL INCLUDE SQLCA; which would break everything since I have a cursor and sql commands. The only thing in my program is a Function prototypes which has no function definition in it. I would like to edit the function to add more functionality to it.

You didn't say what function you're looking for, but generally speaking, you cannot modify functions provided by the system or by a third-party library.  You probably don't even have the C source containing its definition.  You may be able to write a wrapper or alternative function, though.

This is a tagged "c", but it's not clear you're even searching for a C function seeing as you find EXEC SQL INCLUDE SQLCA; and Function prototypes instead of the function, and those are clearly not C. Please clarify.

Stored functions and Oracle predefined functions are within Oracle itself and can be used, in this case,  only from embedded sql sratements.

@JohnBollinger I am using PrintSQLError(). Can I just rename it PrintSQLError1() and do what I want? The oracle documentation makes it sound like it is sql_error() https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B10500_01/appdev.920/a97269/pc_09err.htm. Since we are using two different names I am not sure.

@ikegami fixed. There is no Pro*C tag. Took me awhile to figure out stackoverflow uses oracle-pro-c.

It's unclear quite what you're looking at/for. If that is a built-in function (it's not familiar, but it's been a long time since I've used Pro*C) you could search for it in the library files, but that wouldn't achieve much even if it's there. I'm wondering if you're running a demo program - as you've linked to 9i docs (really?) there's a version here. Not sure what you mean about renaming it - that also suggests you do already have the code. You can just write your own version and call it something else though.

That's not what I said, @noobprogrammer1987.  When I said you could write an alternative, I meant one with its own, distinct name, by which you reference it.

@AlexPoole I am looking for a function named PrintSQLError(). My third sentence said I did search the libraries I have searched the $ORACLE_HOME/precomp/public directory.. Is there another location of libraries? No I am not using a demo program. I work for an old company that has been around for awhile. When companies have things that work they do not like changing them. We use old sunos servers and old oracle databases. When you search for sqlca.sqlerrm.sqlerrmc or sqlca.sqlerrm.sqlerrml the link provided is what you find. Running out of characters.

@AlexPoole how did you find PrintSQLError() in the oracle documentation? I did a google search oracle PrintSQLError() and did not find anything useful. Since John above said I could not modify it I wanted to rename it PrintSQLError1() and create my own version of it.

@JohnBollinger PrintSQLError1() has its own distinct name. I added a 1 to the end of it.

I did not miss the "1", @noobprogrammer1987.  But you asked whether you could rename the system function PrintSQLError() to PrintSQLError1(), which you cannot, as I said.  You can create and use your own function named PrintSQLError1(), as I also said, but that's not the same thing.

"Is there another location of libraries?" - no idea, you haven't said anything about your build process or which libraries (or object files) you link to. It could be a function in your own code, or a company library (you said you removed #include, but what about just extern?), or an Oracle library. And you haven't said how you searched that directory. But unless it's defined in your own code, it doesn't really matter, you can't realistically change or even rename a function in an existing library. I don't know why you want to do that instead of creating your own function.

@JohnBollinger ok then I would like to create my own version of PrintSQLError1(). Still need to find PrintSQLError() so I can take a look at it to create my own version. Not sure what is in it.

I think you can run a program that calls PrintSQLError() through the Pro*C (pre)compiler to get C source code, which you can then examine, but I suspect that you will find that disappointing.  Very likely that function call either will remain unchanged, or it will be replaced with code involving some other function call that is about as opaque to you.  In all likelihood, you will not be able to use the source for that function to create your own version.  But again, you may be able to wrap the existing function so as to re-use it instead of reimplementing it from scratch.

@AlexPoole I searched like this find /usr/include -type f -exec grep -i "PrintSQLError" {} + 2>/dev/null and find /opt/oracle/oracle_19.0.0.0/precomp/public -type f -exec grep -i "PrintSQLError" {} + 2>/dev/null. Then after you mentioned build process or libraries I looked more closely at the compilation message and saw there were a lot of things in /opt/oracle/oracle_19.0.0.0/ so I also did find /opt/oracle/oracle_19.0.0.0/ -type f -exec grep -i "PrintSQLError" {} + 2>/dev/null. Running out of character.

@AlexPoole I do not see extern anywhere in my program. My goal is to create my own function. Would just like to look at the code currently there so I can create my own version of it. That is my goal. That is why I am trying to find it.

@JohnBollinger how do I wrap the existing function? I am not familiar with this.

@noobprogrammer1987 to "wrap" means your function calls the other one and does something with the the results.

@JohnBollinger it seems like the results are just printf and fprintf statements. Not sure how to do anything with that.
